# Howto create a branch from tag in CVS with intelliJ

Tags: branch, intellij-idea, cvs

I checked a specific tag representing some release from CVS using intelliJ Idea 9.0. Now I made few fixes to the code and want to create a branch for the same release starting from this tag. So what I want to do is exactly this: Start branch (before I commit my changes it will be the same as the tag) and keep the tag as it is for reference.

I wonder if command `CVS -> Create branch` on the project root in IntelliJ will do the trick. I went through the official IntelliJ doc but it's still unclear to me if the branch will be created from the currently checked out tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **Create branch** should work as you expect.